# Prevent permutations of foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a django Model as follows:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    field_one = models.ForeignKey(Table_One, related_name="field_one")
    field_two = models.ForeignKey(Table_One, related_name="field_two")
```

I know `unique_together` can be used to make sure duplicate entries cant be made.

Eg, if for the above table:

```
unique_together = ['field_one', 'field_two']
```

Then you can enter values such as `A` for `field_one` and `B` for `field_two`. However, you cannot make the same entry again. But this also allows entry `B` for `field_one` and `A` for `field_two`, which according to my controller logic is the same as `A and B`.

I need to make sure that if A and B are entered for the respective fields, B and A cannot be entered again.

How do I allow only entries of unique combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample clean validation code,

```
from django.db.models import Q

def clean(self):
   mn = ModelName.objects.filter(Q(field_one=self.field_one,field_two=field_two)|Q(field_one=self.field_two,field_two=field_one))
   if mn.exists():
      raise ValidationError('Already exist')
```

Comment: This works but `ValidationError` is giving me `'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_dict'` error.

Answer (score 1):

I would override the model's `clean` method and raise a `ValidationError`. It's a place where you can enforce extra constraints on your models.

*Note however that this method will only be called after a ModelForm's is_valid().*

[Validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)