# clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validate_unique'

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django as follows

```
class TwoPlanetKeyword(models.Model):
    planet_one = models.ForeignKey(Planet, related_name="planet_one")
    planet_two = models.ForeignKey(Planet, related_name="planet_two")
    keyword_list = models.TextField(max_length=100000)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Keywords for Two Planet Combination'
        unique_together = ['planet_one', 'planet_two']

    def __str__(self):
        return "Keywords for two planet combination of {} and {}".format(self.planet_one, self.planet_two)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        plan_one = self.planet_one
        plan_two = self.planet_two
        try:
            obj_val = TwoPlanetKeyword.objects.get(Q(planet_one=plan_one, planet_two=plan_two) | Q(planet_one=plan_two, planet_two=plan_one))
            raise ValidationError({
                        NON_FIELD_ERRORS: [
                            'This combination exists',
                        ],
                    })
        except TwoPlanetKeyword.DoesNotExist:
            super(TwoPlanetKeyword, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The idea here is that to basically prevent permutations of fields in the table from being entered as detailed here [Prevent permutations of foreign keys in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740009/prevent-permutations-of-foreign-keys-in-django).

This solves the above problem but it gives me a `clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validate_unique'` error when I try to save new entries in the table in Django Admin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the `full_clean` method. It wasn't really designed to be overridden. The idea is that you write a custom clean method (as you have done) and then when you call `obj.full_clean()`, the base implementation will call `obj.clean()` for you.

Note that `clean()` does not take any args or kwargs, so you can remove them from the signature. Your error is because you were passing the `validate_unique` keyword argument from `full_clean` to the superclass' clean method.

```
def clean(self):
   ...
   super(TwoPlanetKeyword, self).clean()
```

See the docs on [validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) for more details.

Comment: See [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945339/is-this-the-way-to-validate-django-model-fields/12945692#12945692) about whether or not you want to call `full_clean` in the save method.